# можно ли дозаписать в файл zip в конец файла не распаковывая его на диске на Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, zip, sh

Как дозаписать в файл упакованный в zip не распаковывая его на Linux из скрипта? Может можно распаковать в оперативку и там дописать и запаковать заново? 
Есть идея монтировать раздел в оперативной памяти для этого, но кажется, что это не лучший вариант

Comment: Ну /tmp в оперативке уже существует, можно распаковывать туда (впрочем, я не помню, настроено ли оно по умолчанию на оперативку в centos)

Answer (score 3):

Обновить существующий архив новыми или измененными файлами, рекурсивно:

`zip -ur ARCH.zip FOLDER|FILE ...`